# StackPanel orientation set in code behind

Tags: wpf, orientation, stackpanel

I want to set my `StackPanel` `Orientation` property to vertical in code behind. I cant find `Enum` that I can set Vertical.

```
 var panel = new StackPanel();
 panel.Orientation = Vertical;
```

Comment: Why do it in code behind (of the view, presumably)? Why not just bind it?

Comment: @slugster you mean bind in xaml?

Comment: I sure do. Normally you would bind it to a property, and the property will return the enum value. The property can be notified (which has the effect of causing the binding to update) if something happens, i.e. a window resize takes place.

Comment: @slugster The reason doing on code behind is i want to create dynamic content

Comment: You can do that with [Data templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @slugster Yes, but this StackPanel inside of my grid that I don't know how many rows or columns would have, that's why I'm creating dynamic grid and dynamic stackpanel, ThanQ, for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752328(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var panel = new StackPanel();
panel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
```

May be helpful for researchers